# Precision-recall curve for highly imbalanced multi-class classification task

Tags: classification, roc, precision-recall

I would like to measure the performance of my network on a multi-class classification problem and wanted to use the precision-recall curve. I have four classes, of which three are extremely underrepresented (2%, 2%, 3% and 93%). However, the important classes are the underrepresented classes. I read that the precision-recall curve is more reliable and informative than the ROC curve, especially for imbalanced datasets (see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4349800/) and [here](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0118432)).

However, I wondered how I correctly evaluate the performance with this measure. Do I only compute the precision-recall curve for the minority classes, or do I consider each class equally? What is the correct approach if the detection of the minority class is very important?

Comment: It is entirely inappropriate to envision this as a classification task as opposed to estimation of tendencies.  See http://fharrell.com/post/classification .  Classification is used only for common categories and even then is less useful than probability estimation.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for the input! But I don't see how this can solve my problem.

Comment: Then state your ultimate goal and let's discuss.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to see how good my model handles the underrepresented but important cases.

Comment: That is not the ultimate goal.  What makes you want to develop the model in the first place?  What is the decision task or prediction you seek?